# IE11 (other IE?) background color and border

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The following styles causes the issue shown in the image. As you can see the background-color doesn't fill correctly. Any thoughts?

```
.button{
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:46px;
    color:#57595E;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    width:158px;
    height:46px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #57595E;
}
.button:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#57595E;
}
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: i dont wanna download your code, can you make a fiddle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a mixin I was using was adding `background-clip: padding-box;` and this was causing the issue.